# How much novelty should I add to my previous paper to get it published in New journal?

Tags: publications, journals

I published an article in a journal, then I realized that I Can add two other ideas to it and then get it published in more sophisticated journal than previous one.
The question is : Can I publish my same previous article (same title, same sections, etc) the only diffrence would be : two added sections that represent about 30% of the article ?

Comment: In my area (electrical and electronics), a good/top journal likes fresh ideas that other people can build on.  So in your case, it will be a reject.  Also, I would also definitely reject your paper due to self plagiarism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems unlikely. I doubt that an editor of a reputable journal would accept it, knowing the details. And it would be an ethical lapse to obscure the details, of course.

You can, however, write an extension of the old work, citing it as usual. But the new results would have to stand on their own to pass review. If they don't, then an option is to continue work until you have something that editors and reviewers (not readers here) find sufficiently "interesting" and novel.

Comment: A good journal would likely sink the second submission for lack of novelty; a referee would also likely briefly scan recent work of the author to precisely check against such duplication.

Comment: How would a referee scan recent work of the author - if by referee you mean reviewer then they shouldn't know who the author is? Or is this something the journal would do before sending it out for peer review?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth, most reviewing is single blind. The reviewer knows who the author is. Double blind occurs but is less common.